# Waypoints and infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll, jquery-waypoints

I'm building an infinite scroll page on Wordpress using the [Ajax Load More](https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/add-ons/previous-post/) plugin. I can make it scroll forever, but, I have one problem: I use waypoints to show and hide a sticky navbar with the title of the post and share buttons.

It's always the same waypoints: `#Capa` and `#SigaANDBotoes`.

On the first post, it runs ok. But, when the next is called via Ajax, it does not. For what I am reading, it should refresh or be destroyed / recreated, so it could do it all over again when the next #Capa and `#SigaANDBotoes` appear.

I tried a lot of things that I read around the Internet, but I couldn't find the solution for this. Any help?

This is the Waypoints.js code that I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Capa').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('#Barra').css('display', 'block');
    if (direction === 'down') {
      $('#Barra').addClass('fadeInDownBig').removeClass('fadeOutUpBig');
    } else if (direction === 'up') {
      $('#Barra').addClass('fadeOutUpBig').removeClass('fadeInDownBig');
    }
  }, { offset: '-100%' });


 $('#SigaANDBotoes').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('#Barra').css('display', 'block');
    if (direction === 'down') {
      $('#Barra').addClass('fadeOutUpBig').removeClass('fadeInDownBig');
    } else if (direction === 'up') {
      $('#Barra').addClass('fadeInDownBig').removeClass('fadeOutUpBig');
    }
  }, { offset: '100%' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution is REALLY simple. There's no need to refresh, to destroy or to whatever. All you need is to use CLASSES, not IDs, since IDs are unique and the waypoints were locked to them.

So here's the final code :P

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.Capa').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('.Barra').css('display', 'block');
    if (direction === 'down') {
      $('.Barra').addClass('fadeInDownBig').removeClass('fadeOutUpBig');
    } else if (direction === 'up') {
      $('.Barra').addClass('fadeOutUpBig').removeClass('fadeInDownBig');
    }
  }, { offset: '-100%' });


 $('.SigaANDBotoes').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('.Barra').css('display', 'block');
    if (direction === 'down') {
      $('.Barra').addClass('fadeOutUpBig').removeClass('fadeInDownBig');
    } else if (direction === 'up') {
      $('.Barra').addClass('fadeInDownBig').removeClass('fadeOutUpBig');
    }
  }, { offset: '100%' });
});
```